# PHP Getting Blob url after uploaded to Azure storage

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In .NET Azure Storage SDK, when you upload a blob, you have to create a blob reference, and after upload this blob, some metadata are populated.

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
```

So, after upload the file I can get the azure storage url with

```
blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri
```

But for PHP, call to createBlockBlob method is returning a CopyBlobResult object which doesn't contains the blob url.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the model [`CopyBlobResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/CopyBlobResult.php) does not contain the property `url` of blob. Because the Storage SDK for PHP implements with REST APIS, according https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/Put-Blob?redirectedfrom=MSDN, the API does not response the blob's url.

And in the Storage SDK repository, we can find [`Blob`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/Blob.php#L48) model contains the url property and which is used in [`list blobs`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/ListBlobsResult.php).

Actually, the blob's url is simple so that we can generate it by ourself after we successfully update the blob to Azure. There is no necessary to leverage SDK.

The Blob's url should be in the format : `https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<blob_name>`.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I end up doing and it's working fine.